JPA - Criteria API to query jsonb column in postgres
I have a table called cities and this table has 2 columns user_id and elements_list. user_id is of type varchar(255) and elements_list is of type jsonb
this elements_list is an array of objects, and each object has 2 fields.
ex of elements_list:
[{"id":0,"type":"MY_TYPE_1","position":0},{"id":0,"type":"MY_TYPE_2"}]

I am now, using jpa criteria api, to create a query that searches all records with given user_id and that have in elements_list at least one object with type value that is contained in a string array.
Any ideas how I can do this?
I am trying to do this building 2 criterias and append them
Predicate criteria = criteriaBuilder.conjunction();
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(userId)) {
            criteria = criteriaBuilder.and(criteria, criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("user_id"), "some_value"));
        }

And then I am getting difficulties building the criteria for the type
List<String>functionalityTypeNames= List.of("type1", "type2");
Predicate typePredicate = criteriaBuilder.isTrue(criteriaBuilder.function("jsonb_array_elements_text",
                    Boolean.class, root.get("elements_list"), criteriaBuilder.literal("type")).in(functionalityTypeNames));
            criteria = criteriaBuilder.and(criteria, typePredicate);

But this is not working. Any Ideias how I can build the criteria for the "type"?
